# Why match media in react does not work properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey friends help me please,

I am testing a media query in JavaScript and it doesn't work properly.
The condition is met with a measure before, for example:

If it is `min-with: 992px`, the condition is met when the screen exceeds the width of 893px.

Why does this happen? Working in vanilla JavaScript if it works perfectly.

**CODE**

```js
const mql = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 992px)");
   
    useEffect(() => {
      
        mql.addEventListener("change", resize);
        function resize(e) {
            if (e.matches) { // If media query matches
             
                console.log(window.screen.width);
               
            }
        }
        return () => {
            mql.removeEventListener("change", resize);
        }
    },[mql]);
```

**CAPTURE**

[image]

Comment: Try instead window.screen.width the window.innerWidth. The screen.width is the whole screen width and not just the document window width as the media query focusing.

Comment: `window.screen` is a reference to the OS screen the browser window is rendered on. I get `1920` regardless of the window's width.

Answer (score 1):

This works. [Tested](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-lamport-9mn5z?file=/src/App.js)

```js
  useEffect(() => {
      const mql = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 992px)");
      mql.addEventListener("change", resize);
      function resize(e) {
          if (e.matches) { // If media query matches
              console.log("more than 992");
          } else {
             console.log("less than 992")
          }
      }
      return () => {
          mql.removeEventListener("change", resize);
      }
  },[]);
```

Comment: if you put mql outside useEffect and don't memorize it  (useMemo) then on each render you create new and  you trigger useEffect and then on each render you attach and detach event listener. This is not necessary

Comment: but this no work me. that error persist. thank you for answer me